# (Next/react) SWR refresh from button click in child component - can I use a callback?? (function to function)

Tags: reactjs, callback, next.js

I'm making a shopping cart component with Next.js and having an issue refreshing cart data after updating it. My cart component is a function as recommended on Next.js documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side) and I have a component inside this called products.js, containing my list of products, which each have +/- buttons to adjust their qty (post to the database).

My database updates, but I need to re-fetch the data clientside on the cart component. I've realized I can re-fetch the swr call using swrs 'mutate', but when I try to pass a callback function from my cart.js to products.js it shows up in console log, but isn't called on my button click.

I have tried `cartUpdate = cartUpdate.bind(this)` and also looked into hooks the last couple days and tried other things but could use some advice.

If cart.js were a class component I would bind my `cartUpdate` function before passing it down to product.js and this would work, but I can't seem to do the same when it's function to function vs class to function.

I've been on this a couple of days and I'm not sure If I'm trying to go against some rules I don't know about or how I can re-fetch my data while still keeping my code separated and somewhat clean.

products.js:

```
export default function productsection ({products, cart, cartproducts, feUpdate}){
    console.log("feUpdate", feUpdate)
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map((product, i) => (
                <div className="flex-column justify-content-center mx-2"> 
                <div className="mx-auto card w-100 p-2 my-2">
                <div className="card-body ">
                    <h5 className="card-title text-center">{product.name}</h5>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">

                        {/* <p>Size Selected: {product.size}</p> */}
                        {/* <p>Total: {product.price * props.cartproducts[i].qty} USD</p> */}

                    <button className='btn btn-light mx-2' onClick={() => {
                        fetch(`/api/db/editCartProducts`,{
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({task: 'ADD', orderid: cart.orderid, productid: product.productid})
                        }).then(res => {console.log("adding: " + product.name + " from cart.", "id: " + product.productid); () => feUpdate(); console.log("passed update")})
                    }}
                    >
                    Add
                    </button>
                    <p className="px-2">Price: {product.price} USD EA</p>
                        <p className="px-2">{product.description}</p>
                    <p>Quantity: {cartproducts[i].qty}</p>
                    <button className='btn btn-light mx-2' onClick={() => {
                        fetch(`/api/db/editCartProducts`,{
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({task: 'REMOVE', orderid: cart.orderid, productid: product.productid})
                        }).then(res => {console.log("removing: " + product.name + " from cart.", "id: " + product.productid);() => feUpdate(); console.log("passed update")})
                    }}>
                    Remove
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

cart.js: (main points are `cartUpdate()` & `ProductSection` which I'm passing `cartUpdate` into)

```
function Cart (props){

    const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(args[0], {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({[args[2]]:args[1]})
      }).then(res => res.json())

    let User = Cookies.get('User')

    async function cartUpdate(){
        console.log("mutate called");
        console.log("isValidated: ", isValidating)
        mutate();
        console.log(cartitems);
        console.log("isValidated: ", isValidating)
    }


        const { data: user, error} = useSWR(() => [url1, User, "User"], fetcher, {suspense: false });
        console.log("User returned: ", user)
        const { data: cart, error2} = useSWR(() => [url2, user.customerid, 'User'], fetcher, { suspense: false });
        console.log("Cart returned: ", cart)
        // const OrderId = Cookies.get('orderid')
        const { data: cartitems, error3, mutate, isValidating} = useSWR(() => [url3, cart.orderid, 'orderid'], fetcher, { suspense: false });
        console.log("Cart items: ", cartitems)
        console.log("before productdetails call")
        const { data: productdetails, error4} = useSWR(() => [url4, cartitems, 'productids'], fetcher, { suspense: false });
        console.log("productdetails: ", productdetails)


        let itemtotal = 0;
        let costtotal = 0;
        if(productdetails && cartitems){
            productdetails.forEach((product, i) => {
                itemtotal = itemtotal + (cartitems[i].qty);
                costtotal = costtotal + (product.price * cartitems[i].qty)
            })
            console.log("totals: ", itemtotal, costtotal)
        }


    if (productdetails) {
        console.log(props)
        // foreach to get total price of cart and total items count.


        return (
            <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <Header name={user.fname}/>
                <div className={!isValidating? "card text-center" : "text-center"}>isValidating??</div>
                <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                <button onClick={() => feUpdate()}>Big Update Button</button>
                    <ProductSection feUpdate={cartUpdate}  products={productdetails} cart={cart} cartproducts={cartitems} />
                    <Summery itemtotal={itemtotal} costtotal={costtotal}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just to close this off, I came back to it after working on other areas of the project and realized it was as simple as using a normal function call instead of arrow function e.g. `.then(res => {feUpdate()})` don't know how I overlooked this or what was going on with testing before but it's working now. I guess taking a break and coming back with fresh eyes does the trick.

Answer (score 34):

Are you using the global `mutate` (yes there're 2 of them)? Then you need to pass a SWR key to it.

Global `mutate`:

```js
import useSWR, { mutate } from 'swr'

...

const { data } = useSWR(key, fetcher)
mutate(key) // this will trigger a refetch
```

Or using bound `mutate`, and you don't need to pass the `key`:

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'

...

const { data, mutate } = useSWR(key, fetcher)
mutate() // this will trigger a refetch
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using bound mutate as shown in the cart.js code. Mutate is working, what I'm struggling to do is call this from a child component.

Comment: Maybe all the code made it confusing, sorry. I'm really just trying to figure out how I can do a callback function when the parent component is not a class OR if there are any other options for my usecase.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! So clean. Should be the accepted answer since it solves this problem in general ie the need to refresh state on a random button click somewhere in the code.

Comment: @DanielBalloch Just pass down a function as props to the child component where you want to call mutate() from.

Comment: What if the key is dynamically constructed?